# Repeated value in ColA and ColC

Tags: excel, vba

There is a trivial error but I still don't want it to show up. This is a screenshot of a single generated record. As you can see in ColA the path of the file, in column B the user data (name, surname, address, etc), while for the other columns (C, D, E, F, etc) a certain data. 
Now, first of all, I don't know why the path is repeated for a number of rows equal to the total number of rows used for column B and above all I don't know why the data of column B are partially copied also in column C.

[ie1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nGtg.png)
[image]

Here is the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeCode1()
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim rnum As Long
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim Mybook As Workbook
    Dim src1 As Range, src2 As Range, src3 As Range, src4 As Range, src5 As Range, src6 As Range, src7 As Range, src8 As Range, src9 As Range, src10 As Range, src11 As Range
    Dim destrange As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim f

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Font.Size = 36
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Please Wait"
    rnum = 3

    MyFiles = ""
    Call GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders(Level:=1, ExtChoice:=0, _
                          FileFilterOption:=0, FileNameFilterStr:="")

    If MyFiles <> "" Then

        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(13))
        For Each f In MySplit

            Set Mybook = Workbooks.Open(f)
            Set src1 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C10:C14")
            Set src2 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A11:A11")
            Set src3 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A16:A16")
            Set src4 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C16:C16")
            Set src5 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D16:D16")
            Set src6 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("E16:E16")
            Set src7 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D17:D17")
            Set src8 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("E17:E17")
            Set src9 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D18:D18")
            Set src10 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D19:D19")
            Set src11 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D20:D20")
            'max # of rows to be added...
            Rcount = Application.Max(src1.Rows.Count, src2.Rows.Count, src3.Rows.Count, src4.Rows.Count, src5.Rows.Count, src6.Rows.Count, src7.Rows.Count, src8.Rows.Count, src9.Rows.Count, src10.Rows.Count, src11.Rows.Count)

            If rnum + Rcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Exit For
            Else

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A").Resize(Rcount).Value = f

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "B").Resize(src1.Rows.Count, _
                                                src1.Columns.Count).Value = src1.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "B").Offset(0, src1.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src1.Rows.Count, src1.Columns.Count).Value = src1.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "C").Resize(src2.Rows.Count, _
                                                src2.Columns.Count).Value = src2.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "C").Offset(0, src2.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src2.Rows.Count, src2.Columns.Count).Value = src2.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "D").Resize(src3.Rows.Count, _
                                                src3.Columns.Count).Value = src3.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "D").Offset(0, src3.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src3.Rows.Count, src3.Columns.Count).Value = src3.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "E").Resize(src4.Rows.Count, _
                                                src4.Columns.Count).Value = src4.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "E").Offset(0, src4.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src4.Rows.Count, src4.Columns.Count).Value = src4.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "F").Resize(src5.Rows.Count, _
                                                src5.Columns.Count).Value = src5.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "F").Offset(0, src5.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src5.Rows.Count, src5.Columns.Count).Value = src5.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "G").Resize(src6.Rows.Count, _
                                                src6.Columns.Count).Value = src6.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "G").Offset(0, src6.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src6.Rows.Count, src6.Columns.Count).Value = src6.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "H").Resize(src7.Rows.Count, _
                                                src7.Columns.Count).Value = src7.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "H").Offset(0, src7.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src7.Rows.Count, src7.Columns.Count).Value = src7.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "I").Resize(src8.Rows.Count, _
                                                src8.Columns.Count).Value = src8.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "I").Offset(0, src8.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src8.Rows.Count, src8.Columns.Count).Value = src8.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "J").Resize(src9.Rows.Count, _
                                                src9.Columns.Count).Value = src9.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "J").Offset(0, src9.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src9.Rows.Count, src9.Columns.Count).Value = src9.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "K").Resize(src10.Rows.Count, _
                                                src10.Columns.Count).Value = src10.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "K").Offset(0, src10.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src10.Rows.Count, src10.Columns.Count).Value = src10.Value

                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "L").Resize(src11.Rows.Count, _
                                                src11.Columns.Count).Value = src11.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "L").Offset(0, src11.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src11.Rows.Count, src11.Columns.Count).Value = src11.Value

                rnum = rnum + Rcount

            End If

            Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        Next f
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit

    End If

    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Ready"

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: `BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A").Resize(Rcount).Value = f`  if you only want the file path in one cell then don't use the `Resize()`.

Comment: yes, I only removed resize and little more, you can see my answer below. But there is a new thing about this code, look at the link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806259/extrapolate-cell-value-every-11-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Variatus I thank you for giving your contribution, it helped me understand the structure you used but left so it gives me "next without for". However, I have remedied, as you have done, modifying my original code, so transforming only this part of code in this way and now it works.

```
    BaseWks.Cells(Rnum, "A").Value = f

    BaseWks.Cells(Rnum, "B").Resize(src1.Rows.Count, _
                                    src1.Columns.Count).Value = src1.Value
    'BaseWks.Cells(Rnum, "B").Offset(0, src1.Columns.Count) _
                 .Resize(src1.Rows.Count, src1.Columns.Count).Value = src1.Value

    BaseWks.Cells(Rnum, "C").Value = src2.Value

    BaseWks.Cells(Rnum, "D").Value = src3.Value
    'BaseWks.Cells(Rnum, "D").Offset(0, src3.Columns.Count) _
                 .Resize(src3.Rows.Count, src3.Columns.Count).Value = src3.Value
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Variatus there is a new thing about this code, look at the link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806259/extrapolate-cell-value-every-11-rows

Comment: For me, the "new thing" is easier to implement in the code I wrote than in the code you already have. Therefore your new question isn't for me. I would look into it if you would adopt the code I offered below and publish it with your new question. My modifications to your original code need your input. Before that input has been absorbed it isn't, regretfully, worth my while to pile on more changes.

Comment: @Variatus I have adopted your code, but as I said, it indicates "next without for". would you be able to solve this problem that arises from your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have re-written your code, alas without testing it because I don't have data. The focus of my effort was to make it apparent to you how your code replicates values several times over. I invite you to read through the code and take note of my comments. I am confident you will then be able to identify the points where I may have suggested to take out some features that you require. It will be easy to reinstate them because I left most of the original code in place.

```
Sub MergeCode1()

    Dim MyBook As Workbook
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim Src(1 To 11) As Range           ' src1 becomes Src(1) etc
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim f As Variant
    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim Ranges() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Font.Size = 36
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Please Wait"

    MyFiles = ""
    Call GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders( _
                          Level:=1, ExtChoice:=0, _
                          FileFilterOption:=0, _
                          FileNameFilterStr:="")
    ' not clear where MyFiles might get a value from
    If MyFiles <> "" Then
        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(13))
        Ranges = Split("C10:C14,A11,A16,C16,D16,E16,D17,E17,D18,D19,D20", ",")
        Rnum = 3
        For Each f In MySplit
            Set MyBook = Workbooks.Open(f)
            With MyBook.Worksheets(1)
                For i = LBound(Src) To UBound(Src)
                    Set Src(i) = .Range(Ranges(i - 1))
                    Rcount = Application.Max(Rcount, Src(i).Rows.Count)
                Next i
            End With

            If Rnum + Rcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                MyBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Exit For
            Else
                With BaseWks
                    ' this command fills several rows in columns A with f
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "A").Resize(Rcount).Value = f
                    .Cells(Rnum, "A").Value = f

                    .Cells(Rnum, "B").Resize(Src(1).Rows.Count, _
                                             Src(1).Columns.Count).Value = Src(1).Value
                    ' this command writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "B").Offset(0, Src(1).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(1).Rows.Count, Src(1).Columns.Count).Value = Src(1).Value

                    ' All ranges from Src(2) and up have a single row and single column
                    ' Therefore, in the following Resizing can be omitted and
                    ' .Offset(0, Src(2).Columns.Count) can be hard-coded as .Offset(0, 1)
                    '   which writes the same value to the next column.
'                    .Cells(Rnum, "C").Resize(Src(2).Rows.Count, _
'                                             Src(2).Columns.Count).Value = Src(2).Value
                    ' revised:-
                    .Cells(Rnum, "C").Value = Src(2).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "C").Offset(0, Src(2).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(2).Rows.Count, Src(2).Columns.Count).Value = Src(2).Value
                    ' revised:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "C").Offset(0, 1).Value = Src(2).Value

'                    .Cells(Rnum, "D").Resize(Src(3).Rows.Count, _
'                                                    Src(3).Columns.Count).Value = Src(3).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
'                    .Cells(Rnum, "D").Offset(0, Src(3).Columns.Count) _
'                                 .Resize(Src(3).Rows.Count, Src(3).Columns.Count).Value = Src(3).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "E").Value = Src(4).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "E").Offset(0, Src(4).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(4).Rows.Count, Src(4).Columns.Count).Value = Src(4).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "F").Value = Src(5).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "F").Offset(0, Src(5).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(5).Rows.Count, Src(5).Columns.Count).Value = Src(5).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "G").Value = Src(6).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "G").Offset(0, Src(6).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(6).Rows.Count, Src(6).Columns.Count).Value = Src(6).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "H").Value = Src(7).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "H").Offset(0, Src(7).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(7).Rows.Count, Src(7).Columns.Count).Value = Src(7).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "I").Value = Src(8).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "I").Offset(0, Src(8).Columns.Count) _
                    '             .Resize(Src(8).Rows.Count, Src(8).Columns.Count).Value = Src(8).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "J").Value = Src(9).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "J").Offset(0, Src(9).Columns.Count) _
                    '            .Resize(Src(9).Rows.Count, Src(9).Columns.Count).Value = Src(9).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "K").Value = Src(10).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "K").Offset(0, Src(10).Columns.Count) _
                    '            .Resize(Src(10).Rows.Count, Src(10).Columns.Count).Value = Src(10).Value

                    .Cells(Rnum, "L").Value = Src(11).Value
                    ' The command below writes the same value as above to the next column:-
                    '.Cells(Rnum, "L").Offset(0, src(11).Columns.Count) _
                    '            .Resize(src(11).Rows.Count, src(11).Columns.Count).Value = src(11).Value
                End With
                Rnum = Rnum + Rcount
            End If

            MyBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next f
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Ready"
End Sub
```

Comment: I have modified the code, hopefully eliminating the error. FYI, I added an `End With` above this line of code: `If Rnum + Rcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then`. Please resolve the fate of all the remmed out code before moving to the next modification. Good luck.